# How can I change the size of my Gif with a absolutelayout?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a gif in my project that i can see clear in my project. However when I try to change it to a certain position with a absolutelayout the width/height changes accordingly but the "gif" itself does not change size so for example i can only see the top left corner of the gif if i decrease the size by a lot.

My code looks like this:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GifView_iOS))]
namespace Project.iOS
{
 public class GifView_iOS : IGif
 {
   public string Get()
   {
     return NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
   }
 }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IGif
{
   string Get();
}
```

Control:

```
public class Gif : WebView
{
public string GifSource
{
    set
    {
        string imgSource = value; 
        var html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        html.Html = String.Format
            (@"<html><body style='background: #000000;'><img src='{0}' /></body></html>",
             imgSource);
        SetValue(SourceProperty, html);
    }
  }
}
```

How I use it in xaml:

```
<controls:Gif GifSource = "myGif.gif"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  />
```

So now the gif changes to my absolutelayout values, however, the "gif" itself does not change so in my case i can only see the top left corner of the gif now. How can I make so that the gif also changes it's size with a absolutelayout?

Comment: can you please share the Interface Implementation for the Android and Windows Phone, actually I am trying to use the GIF image but didn't get succeed. Thank You.

Comment: and 1 more question, where have you used the IGif interface, I am not sure for this.

Comment: I am only working with the iOS part now.

Comment: please let me know if you are able to do the same with the Android.

Comment: yeah i plan to implement it there after i fix ios part

Comment: You are only changing the size of the WebView that is showing the GIF. I believe there is a property on a UIWebView (iOS's native web view that renders a Forms WebView) to "ScalePagesToFit" and that should resize the web page to fit the web view. I believe you will also have to create a custom renderer to set this property on the native UIWebView.